# Fast/vectorized iterating and updating of numpy 2D array

Tags: python, performance, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

This question is quite close to my heart as I have been doing something like this for almost 2 years and always wondered if there is a vectorized way of modifying large array/dataframe when row `i` depends upon row `i-1`, i.e., when recursion sounds mandatory. I am very keen to hear if there are either ***clever algorithms*** or ***clever tools (cython, numba, get rid of redundant operations, etc.)*** to optimize the runtime.

**Problem**:
I have 3 big numpy arrays: `x`, `y` and `z` of shape (1million by 500), (1million by 500) and (1million by 1). Clip/winsorize each element in any given row `i` of `x` based on whether `|(x[i] - x[i-1]) * z[i] / y[i]| > thresh`. I am doing this in the following way which is taking extremely long time for my simulations to run (esp when this step repeats thousands of time to tune the hyperparameters):

```
t = x.copy()
t[0] = np.clip(t[0] * z[0]/ y[0], -1 * thresh, thresh) * y[0] / z[0]
for i in range(1, t.shape[0]):
    t[i] = np.clip((t[i] - t[i-1]) * z[i] / y[i], -1* thresh, thresh) * y[i] / z[i] + t[i-1]
```

**Sample input**:

```
import numpy as np
import random
x = np.random.rand(1000000, 500)
y = np.random.rand(1000000, 500)
z = np.random.rand(1000000, 1)
thresh = 0.7
```

**Edit**: *Modified to remove append as suggested by* @Mad Physicist *and redundant if-else as suggested by* @Pedro Maia

Comment: Why do you have an if statement that is executed 1 mi times? if you want to do it only once move outside the loop

Comment: @PedroMaia fair point. I have modified it now.

Comment: Don't use append for one thing. It reallocates the entire array every time

Comment: Consider using cython or numba for something like this.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks - I got rid of append. Could you show me how to use numba and cython in this case. (my simulation is running on spark so assuming that numba/cython wouldn't cause issues there). Thanks a lot

Comment: The tutorial is your friend here. I'm not going to be able to teach you a new library in the scope of an answer

Comment: @MadPhysicist sure. From your experience what order of magnitude performance improvement I can get by going to either Numba or cython. Or which one is generally a recommended solution in this case OR I got to try both?

Comment: I think Numba should be a bit better in this case as it should be quite simple to use it and should also provide a good speed up.

Comment: In this case, either will do fine. I'd expect anywhere between 10-100x improvement.

Comment: Note that due to the latency of the division and the data dependency chain, this is faster to put parenthesis on `z[i] / y[i]` and `y[i] / z[i]` (unless the tiny precision change in this case is critical in your case). Using `-thresh` instead of `-1*thresh` is also more efficient (bu Numba could optimize this one).

Comment: @JérômeRichard and @MadPhysicist I tried to use `@jit(nopython=True)` which worked on similar `numpy` iteration function (didn't work here as `np.clip` is not supported by `numba`). However, diff of `time.time()` before and after using `numba` and without `numba` showed a little difference (`numba` slightly worse - may be I need to do more to unleash its power).

Comment: You need to *pre-compile the function* or not to take into account the *compilation time* (done the *first time* you call the function). You can for example provide the types to numba so it will compile the function ahead to time. Moreover, note that `@jit(nopython=True)` is equivalent to `@njit` (shorter). Alternatively, there is an AOT compiler in Numba if you want to better control the pre-compilation (but this should not be needed here). Here is an example: `@njit('void(float64[::1], float64, float64[::1], float64[::1])')`

Answer (score 1):

I got 3-4x improvement by using `numba`, another 2x (in total 6-8x) by caching compiled function.

I had to decrease size of `x`, `y`, and `z` due to small RAM on my PC.

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def bottleneck_func3(t, thresh, y, z):
    t[0] = np.clip(t[0] * z[0] / y[0], -1 * thresh, thresh) * y[0] / z[0]
    for i in range(1, t.shape[0]):
        t[i] = np.clip((t[i] - t[i - 1]) * z[i] / y[i], -1 * thresh, thresh) * y[i] / z[i] + t[i - 1]

x = np.random.rand(300000, 500)
y = np.random.rand(300000, 500)
z = np.random.rand(300000, 1)
thresh = 0.7

t = x.copy()
bottleneck_func3(t, thresh, y, z)
```

Note that  [cached function is recompiled each time you modify the file](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/developer/caching.html#cache-clearing), even parts that have nothing to do with cached function.